# Simple way to show group members in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models:

```
class Division(models.Model):
    DIVISIONS = (
        (u'D1', u'Division1'),
        (u'D2', u'Division2'),
        (u'D3', u'Division3'),
    )
    division = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=DIVISIONS)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.division


class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    division = models.ForeignKey(Division)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Is there a way to edit all of the Players from within the Division? I've tried adding a ManyToMany field in Division, but that does not seem to link the two models correctly. This question from [2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180628/django-users-and-groups-show-group-membership-in-admin) hits on what I'm trying to accomplish...is there a more straightforward and contemporary way to edit group membership in Admin from the group and also from the member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [InlineModelAdmin objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) particularly the TabularInline object. Sample code below will let you edit the list of Players belonging to a particular division.

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

class PlayerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Player

class DivisionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        PlayerInline,
    ]
```

As for being able to edit the Division from the Player model, you should already be able to do that, unless you removed it from the list of editable fields. If you plan to change that to a ManyToManyField, you will need to create a [through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) (e.g. Membership) and create the inlines like so:

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

class MembershipInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Membership

class DivisionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        MembershipInline,
    ]

class PlayerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        MembershipInline,
    ]
```

Comment: This is 100% what I was looking for, thanks! So much simpler to implement than the snippet found in the older thread.

Comment: To be fair to the old snippet, it's trying to help show a ManyToMany relationship rather than your ManyToOne.

Comment: I must be sleepy when I wrote this, but I made some corrections on the last section pertaining to Inlines with ManyToMany fields.